# (PyQt) How can I reset the CharFormat of an entire QTextEdit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, formatting, qtextedit

I'm using mergeCharFormat on several words within my QTextEdit, in an effort to highlight them. Something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

def drawGUI():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 50)
    editBox = QtGui.QTextEdit(w)
    text = 'Hello stack overflow, this is a test and tish is a misspelled word'
    editBox.setText(text)

    """ Now there'd be a function that finds misspelled words """

    # Highlight misspelled words
    misspelledWord = 'tish'
    cursor = editBox.textCursor()
    format_ = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
    format_.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("pink")))
    pattern = "\\b" + misspelledWord + "\\b"
    regex = QRegExp(pattern)
    index = regex.indexIn(editBox.toPlainText(), 0)
    cursor.setPosition(index)
    cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.EndOfWord, 1)
    cursor.mergeCharFormat(format_)

    w.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    drawGUI()
```

So, this highlighting feature works exactly as intended. However, I can't find a good way to clear the highlights from the textarea. What is a good method of doing such a thing- essentially just setting the char format of the entire QTextEdit back to its defaults?

What I've tried so far is getting the cursor again, and setting its format to a new format with a clear background, then putting the cursor over the entire selection and using QTextCursor.setCharFormat(), but this appears to do nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying a new `QTextCharFormat` to the whole document works for me:

```
def drawGUI():
    ...
    cursor.mergeCharFormat(format_)

    def clear():
        cursor = editBox.textCursor()
        cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.Document)
        cursor.setCharFormat(QtGui.QTextCharFormat())
        cursor.clearSelection()
        editBox.setTextCursor(cursor)

    button = QtGui.QPushButton('Clear')
    button.clicked.connect(clear)

    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
    layout.addWidget(editBox)
    layout.addWidget(button)
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know there was just a .select() for cursor, somehow missed that in the docs.